# Need help on UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, update

This is my table `tracks`

```
id | art | time
```

- `id` is an auto-increment primary key
- `art` is a varchar(512)
- `time` is a timestamp not null predefined as `current_timestamp` and `on update current_timestamp`

It seems really a dumb question but after one hour of tries, someone could please tell me why this simple query doesn't `UPDATE` the rows with empty `art` field but instead `UPDATE` only the time to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

```
UPDATE `tracks` SET `time` = `time` AND `art` = 'default.jpg' WHERE `art` = '';
```

**UPDATE**

I ran `SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE art = '';` and it founds right rows, same using `WHERE TRIM(art) = ''` .
Instead `WHERE art IS NULL` is empty.

**UPDATE2**

This query works but it updates the time and I don't want it.

```
UPDATE `tracks` SET `art` = 'default1.jpg' WHERE `art` = '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial syntax was incorrect

```
UPDATE `tracks` SET `time` = `time` AND `art` = 'default.jpg' WHERE `art` = '';
```

`AND` does not separate the columns to update. They should be separated by commas (`,`)

What you probably wanted was

```
UPDATE `tracks` SET `time` = `time`,`art` = 'default.jpg' WHERE `art` = '';
```

Comment: incredible I've made this mistake, thanks!